# Single page application inside normal SharePoint page

Tags: 2013, web-part

I want to put my single page app inside a normal SharePoint page, what is the best way to do this?

I know I can use the WebPart that will display a page inside an `iFrame`, but this does not look good, and it makes the app within act very buggy. Can this be done some other way, somehow with an content editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not referring to actual SharePoint Apps, I'd say:

1. Upload your application under /_catalogs/masterpage/yourapp. You can create the actual app using Angular, jQuery, etc.
2. Add Content Editor Web Part to SharePoint page, and point it to the app:  /_catalogs/masterpage/youapp/index.html

At least my Usage Analytics application created using Angular and using DataTables, Flot charts and such works fine this way, and I can navigate within the app fluently without page reloads (this of course needs to be handled within the app itself and not part of your single page app).

Comment: I have added the content editor, but what do I write to 'point it' to my app?

Comment: nevermind, I found it. I tried using a scripteditor. Either way, I din't work very well, it displayed some of the page, for example a table, but not the content of the table